# Unable to deploy fbprophet in heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, time-series, requirements, facebook-prophet

I am unable to deploy fbprophet time series model into heroku. Locally, it works well.

The requirements.txt file contains as follows.

```
numpy
pandas
matplotlib
pystan==2.19.1.1
streamlit
plotly
fbprophet
```

Tried:
Kept default pystan without giving the version. Did not work. Error in CLI showing "Pystan loading".

Error:

```
Failed to build pystan fbprophet
Running setup.py install for pystan: started
```

No response after this.

Answer (score 0):

fbprophet is older version try using prophet, if it doesn't work you can install prophet through prebuilt wheels https://pypi.org/project/prophet-prebuilt/1.0.2/#files